# Join set of polylines fast

Tags: performance, algorithm, polyline

## Task

Given a set *S* = { *L<sub>i</sub>* }, *i* ∈ [0,*N*) of polylines *L<sub>i</sub>* = (*p<sub>0</sub>*, …, *p<sub>M<sub>i</sub></sub>*),  join the polylines having common points.

## Example

The polylines *A* = (1, 2, 3, 4), *B* = (6, 5, 4) and *C* = (6, 7, 8) should be joined to form the either polyline *J* = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) or *K* = (8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1).
[image: Example]

## Solution

For every point *p<sub>u</sub>* ∈ *L<sub>i</sub>*, u ∈ { 0, *M<sub>i</sub>* } check for every *L<sub>j</sub>* ∈ *S* \ { *L<sub>i</sub>* } if *p<sub>v</sub>* = *p<sub>u</sub>* ; *p<sub>v</sub>* ∈ *L<sub>j</sub>*, v ∈ { 0, *M<sub>j</sub>* }. If it does, join *L<sub>i</sub>* and *L<sub>j</sub>*.

## Problem

It's very slow, since *N* ≈ 1,000,000 and ∑ M<sub>i</sub> ≈ 100,000,000.

## Question

Do you have a suggestion to improve my naive algorithm?

Comment: could you list the behaviour for corner cases?

Comment: Sorry, I think I don't understand your question well. :-(

Comment: What data structure are you using to represent a line? Are reversing and splicing expensive?

Comment: I can change the data structure to fit the needs of the algorithm. At the moment it's a C#-list (similar to a vector in C++), but that's not immutable.

Comment: I don't know C#, but joining two std::vectors in C++ is expensive (O(M) I think) and you're doing N-1 times, and so is reversing a vector (also O(M)), and you're doing that up to O(N log(N)) times. No wonder it's slow! So would you prefer to improve the algorithm, or pick a data structure where reversing and joining are O(1)?

Comment: I'd prefer to improve the algorithm. I chose lists because I'm joining rarely and I ofter have to lookup the first and the last element of the polyline (constant time for C#-lists and O(N) for linked lists).

Answer (score 0):

Don't join two lines as soon as you find a match. Note the match, and remove the two endpoints from the pool of endpoints under consideration. Then when all matches have been found, start reversing lines. That way each line is reversed once at most.

When you join the lines, it may behoove you to allocate the space for one big line and copy all of the small lines into it. Depending on implementation, joining two lines can be expensive (O(M)), so it's better not to join the lines piecemeal.

Comment: The bottleneck isn't the joining, the bottleneck is checking, since it's O(N^2). I'm Loopings for a way to reduce complexity.

Comment: @user2033412: Then why did you bring ∑Mi into this, when it's irrelevant? Divide the space into bins, compare endpoints that fall in the same bin.